# Issue with perfmon counter value using WMI query

Tags: c#-4.0, wmi, performancecounter, wmi-query, perfmon

I am building EXE and through which i am fetching perfmon counter of application to monitor that using WMI query. I am testing it with my local machine and seems like my code logic gives me incorrect values for some of counters.

Below is my code for one of the counter (**CacheTotalHitRatio**)
[image]

And when i have looked it with **perfmon exe** in my system then it shows me something different as shown below.

[image]

I think  **CacheTotalHitRatio** is in percentage and should not be go beyond 100 but my code gives some higher value. What is problem here OR am i doing something wrong here?

Please let me know if anyone have experience with WMI query.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are susing a preformance counter with raw values (Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications
), try using the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications` class instead.

Comment: @RRUZ Hey Thanks a lot, it's gives me correct value but please tell me what is difference between that? Also i am using same with others counter like Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNET, Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService so in all i need to replace that?Please write down answer so i can mark as answer:) Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exist two types of [Performance Counter Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

- [Formatted Performance Counter Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_hmm_formatted_performance_counter_classes)
- [Raw Performance Counter Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_hmm_raw_performance_counter_classes)

The `Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications` class returns the **raw performance** counter values these values must be transformed (using a formula according to the property and the class) to be displayed, if you uses the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications` class instead  you will get the **calculated data** just as are shown in the  Performance monitor.

Comment: Great! Appreciate with your answer, it's really help me to resolved my issue. thanks