# Perfmon counters not the same as wmi - Memory page faults per sec

Tags: wmi, perfmon

I am trying to create a monitoring app for the sql servers I monitor. So, I wanted to monitor page faults/sec counter under Memory object. However, the results don't seem to match between Perfmon and WMI.

Perfmon returned these values over 10 seconds period:

```
page faults/sec :
12232.6784469901
18202.2436831425
35645.0677427461
54604.051872456
45554.3977163183
38647.3210599721
53292.9450240945
38855.337610983
4435.52408472815
2187.3626966044
```

WMI returned these values over the same 10 second period:

```
PageFaultsPerSec : 
2956
1950
3279
4591
1854
2904
11880
6372
4123
8160
```

Why is it so? Other counters Available MBytes, Commit Limit, and Pool Paged Bytes returned almost identical values between Perfmon and WMI.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: anybody out there to help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461415/issue-with-perfmon-counter-value-using-wmi-query may be useful...